# Assembly : cmp instruction and addressing

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm

I am new to asm and confused...

Here is the loop of my working `strlen` function in `nasm` assembly :

```
        .loop:      inc rax                                                         
                    inc rbx                                                         
                    cmp [rbx], byte 0                                               
                    jne .loop                                                       
                    ret
```

However I have seen in tutorials things like `cmp bl, 0` but when I try that I get the wrong length.

I have tried `cmp [bl],0` but I get an `invalid effective address` error when assembling.

I have also tried `cmp rbx, 0`. But the program never stops so my best guess is I am
comparing a very big address to 0 which never happens.

How do one make sense of this behavior ? Why can't I use `cmp rbx, 0` but some
people are able to use `cmp bl, 0` ?

Please feel free to edit the title if you find a more descriptive one.

Comment: Can you show the full `strlen` procedure you've made, along with an example you've seen where `cmp bl, 0` is used?

Comment: If you load the char into a register, you can compare that against 0.  If no, you need to a memory operand for `cmp`.  And BTW, you're correct that `cmp rbx,0` would be comparing the pointer against NULL; you'll hit an unmapped page before you wrap your pointer around to 0.

Comment: Do you understand exactly what `cmp byte [rbx], 0` means?  There should be lots of tutorials that explain addressing modes and memory vs. register, e.g. find a tutorial or guide linked from https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info and read it.  That should also make it obvious why `cmp [bl], 0` can't even assemble (x86 doesn't allow 8-bit addresses), as well as why it wouldn't do what you wanted even if it could run.

Comment: There is another way of searching for the NUL terminator: [REPNE SCAS](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/scas:scasb:scasw:scasd).

Comment: You don't need to `inc rax`, it's enough to move the start of the string into rax, and then subtract the address of the `0-Byte` you just found, to get the length.

Comment: There's a bug in your function - what will it do when passed an empty string?

Answer (score 2):

To compare the byte at the address I would recommend moving the byte into a register of the correct size and then comparing it. Depending on the calling convention you are using, but assuming the address of the string is passed in rdi, I would suggest something along the following.

```
        .loop:      inc rax                                                         
                    mov bl, [rdi + rax]                                                      
                    cmp bl, byte 0                                               
                    jne .loop                                                       
                    ret
```

EDIT: realized you were trying to determine the length of a string at a given address

Comment: rax is initialized to zero just above .loop.

Comment: Note that you didn't fix the OP's bug of not checking the first byte (perhaps `[rdi+rax-1]`, or init RAX to `-1` before the loop).  Then that's reasonable, but normally you want to use `movzx ecx, byte [rdi + rax]` for byte loads, not create a false dependency and take an ALU uop by merging into the low byte of RBX.  (Or RCX, which is a better choice for strlen because the calling convention lets you modify it without saving).   Of course, going 1 byte at a time is very slow compared to SIMD, so it's only something you'd do as a beginner exercise.

Comment: @PeterCordes: I would normally write rep scasb but then again I'm never writing asm for performance anymore.

Comment: @Joshua: Yeah, that's ok for code-size and simplicity, but not much else.  It only goes 1 byte at a time; only rep movs and rep stos have fast-strings microcode; the conditional repe/repne instructions don't in current CPUs, unfortunately.  `repne scasb` won't branch mispredict per se, but I think tends to stall the front-end.  Although maybe not for short strings where the initial burst of uops covers the length.